# Amazon EBS Volume running ECS cluster gets filled up easily

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am running Amazon ECS Cluster and everything works fine but I noticed that my EBS volume gets filled up quickly. Any time this happens I have to delete the cluster and create it again because even when I select a larger EBS Volume, it still gets filled up.

Anytime this happens and I am trying to run a new task, I get:

```
Status reason
CannotPullContainerError: write /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob059053200: no space left on device"
```

Is there a way I can rectify this or is using Amazon ECS not the best way to go?